# Python calculations using groups to sum

Tags: python, group-by, count, sum, frequency

Good afternoon all,

Bit stuck with the last stage of a calculation.

I have a dataframe which outputs as such:

```
   LaCode   Group   Frequency     
0   718      NaN        2            
1   718       3         1           
2   719       1         4           
3   719       2         10
```

I'm struggling with the percentage calculation which is for each LaCode, ignore where Group is NaN (and just put NaN (or blank) and calculate percentage of the frequency's where Group is known.

Should output as such:

```
Percentage
   NaN
   100
   28.571
   71.428
```

Can anyone help with this? My code doesn't take into account the change in LaCode and I can't work out the correct syntax to incorporate that issue.

Thanks.

Edit: For completeness, I have converted the NaN to an integer that stands out so I can see it (in this instance 0 as that isn't a valid group in the survey)

The code I'm using for calculation was provided to me and I tweaked a little. Works ok when just one LaCode:

```
df['Percentage'] = df[df['Value'] != 0]['Count'].apply(lambda x: x/sum(df[df['Value'] != 0]['Count']))
```

Comment: how are you calculating percentage here?

Comment: See edit: I've put the code I'm using at the bottom. Is this what you wanted?